# Dialog opens outside viewport

Tags: javascript, html, dialog

In case you're on a large page and you've scrolled all the way down. At the bottom is a button which opens a dialog. In my case this dialog opens outside the viewport at the top of the page

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/4btjwj9p/1/)

JS:

```
var showDialogButton = document.getElementById('showDialogButton');

showDialogButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var bronteDialog = document.getElementById('bronteDialog');
  var anchorPoint = document.getElementById('anchor');
  bronteDialog.show(anchorPoint);
});
```

It turns out that the `show` function accepts an argument which is an anchor for the dialog. But whatever I do, the dialog is at the top. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this to the CSS:

```
dialog {
  position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: thanks, that did the trick. Do you also know what the anchor argument is all about ?

Comment: Not sure. It seems like `HTMLDialogElement` is an experimental feature, so it doesn't really surprise me it's not fully functional: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDialogElement

Comment: True. The thing that still is weird I think is that when you use `showModal` ([DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/4btjwj9p/2/)) the dialog is nicely centers. But with `show` you have todo it yourself (somehow). Or do you think this makes sense ?

Comment: That is interesting. I think it just depends on how the browser chooses to implement the feature. Maybe they think that people will generally want a modal centered by default since interaction with elements behind the modal can no longer be interacted with, while a non-modal should just float wherever until the user decides where to put it because interaction is still possible? Just speculation, but that's my guess :)

Comment: Thats indeed the only logical explanation, thnx